# Are there economy-related commands in clean HLDS?

Tags: counter-strike, server-administration

Are there economy-related commands in clean HLDS? I know that there is `mp_startmoney` at very least but I also remeber that there are others like a frag bounty and round winning bounty and many more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know (and checked) there is no command to change the game's economy settings on vanilla servers. Those bounties for example are from a plugin.

With certain plugins you can change weapon costs, give bounties, extra bonuses and other stuff, but for vanilla cs you'll have to live with `mp_startmoney`.

[Here](http://txdv.github.io/cstrike-cvarlist/) is a reference of existing CVars.